# Textarea que chama uma Lista de Usuários quando a tecla F2 é pressionada

Tags: javascript, html

Bom dia

Pessoal foi me passada uma tarefa que esta sendo desafiadora. Preciso desenvolver um `textarea` que quando eu clico na tecla F2, dentro do `textarea`, aparece uma lista contendo os logins do sistema.

Algo parecido foi visto no *Whatsapp*, quando você vai mandar uma mensagem para um grupo você coloca @ e lista seus contatos para marcar o mesmo na mensagem.

Alguém saberia informar como eu faço para que no `textarea` ocorra isso?

Eu pensei da seguinte forma (não sei se seria a forma mais correta):

```html
<!-- language: lang-html -->

<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
        <label for="Comentario"> Comentário </label>
        <div>
          <textarea id="ComentarioText" onkeyup="listaUsuario()" 
               onfocus="this.rows=5" onblur="this.rows=1" rows="1"> 
          </textarea>                                                       
       </div>
    </div>
    <script>    
       function listaUsuario() {

         //Quando clicar sobre o F2 à lista de usuários cadastrados               
         if (event.keyCode == 113) {
            window.alert("O código: " + event.keyCode);
         }
       } 
    </script>
  </body>

<!-- end snippet -->
```

Até capturar a tecla consegui fazer, agora minha dúvida é de como eu faço para subir uma lista de usuários, com base nessa ação?

Não consegui achar algo que me desce alguma luz, alguém poderia me dar um norte para onde seguir?

Comment: Onde está a lista de usuários, e caso esteja num BD, qual  linguagem back-end?

Comment: Vinicius atualmente a lista de usuários esta no mysql na tabela login onde eu tenho loginid e lognome, a linguagem de back-end que vou utilizar é php.

Answer (score 1):

a variável "users" está simulando todos os logins que você recuperou do banco de dados, se colocar o código que usa para recuperar essas informações posso editar esta resposta e te ajudar melhor

```js
let users = [
        {
            login: "Wilbor",
            senha: "asdfa@j12"
        },
        {
            login: "Wilson",
            senha: "wertwet@u7312"
        },
        {
            login: "Junior",
            senha: "yuioyuo@82"
        }
      ];
 function listaUsuario() {
            //Quando clicar sobre o F2 à lista de usuários cadastrados               
            if (event.keyCode == 113) {
                console.log("O código: " + event.keyCode);
                let conteudo='Lista de Usuários:\n';
                for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
                    conteudo+= '\n'+(i+1)+') Login: '+users[i].login+' | Senha: '+users[i].senha;
                }
                const campo = document.getElementById('ComentarioText');
                campo.style.width='300px';
                campo.style.height='200px';
                campo.innerHTML=conteudo;
            }
        }
```

```html
<div>
        <label for="Comentario"> Comentário </label>
        <div>
            <textarea id="ComentarioText" onkeyup="listaUsuario()" 
                onfocus="this.rows=5" onblur="this.rows=1" rows="1"> 
            </textarea>                                                       
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Valeu pelo auxilio

Comment: A comunidade cresce mais quando mais nos dispomos a ajudar nosso próximo, Sucesso!

Answer (score 1):

Vc pode colocar um eventListener na window quando a textarea estiver com focus. Ai vc faz seu if caso o usuário aperte f2 para mostrar um modal que sua lista vai estar dentro.

Aqui tem um exemplo bem básico, mas que acho que pode te ajudar.

```js
let txt = document.querySelector('textarea');

txt.addEventListener('focus', () => {
  console.log('focou: ' + txt);

  function listaUsuario() {
    //Quando o textarea estiver focado, se apartar f2 ele imprime o evento
    if (event.keyCode == 113) {
      console.log("Apertou F2: " + event.keyCode);
      var modal = document.querySelector('.modal');
      modal.classList.add('ativo');
    }
  }
  window.addEventListener('keydown', listaUsuario);
})
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: red;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 50px;
  display: none;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.modal.ativo {
  display: flex;
}

section {
  max-width: max-content;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<p> Se vc focar no textarea abaixo e apertar f2 vai aparece o modal com a lista...</p>

<textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>


<div class="modal">
    <section>minha lista</section>
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda já me deu uma idéia de como proceder

Comment: @EderLuca tranquilo tmj

Answer (score 0):

Mais um exemplo que pode dar uma ajuda!

```js
const users = ['maria','rita','joana'];

function myFunction(event){

  if (event.keyCode === 113){           
     document.getElementById('users').classList.add('show');
  }

}

function createListItens(){
  
   const ul = document.getElementById('users-list');
    
    users.forEach(user => {
      
      const li = document.createElement('li');
      li.innerText = user;
      
      li.addEventListener('click', function(event){ 
        let textarea = document.getElementById('textarea');    
        let value = textarea.value + this.innerText;        
        textarea.value = value;
        document.getElementById('users').classList.remove('show');
      });
      
      ul.appendChild(li);      
    });

}

createListItens();
```

```css
#wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

#users {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100;
  left: 0;
  border: 1px red solid;
  display: none;
}

#users.show {
  display: block;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: gold;
}

li {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px;
}

li:hover {
  background-color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <p>Carrega em F2 para listar usuarios (com o focus na textarea).</p>
  <textarea id="textarea" rows="4" cols="50" onkeyup="myFunction(event,this);"></textarea>
  <div id="users">
    <ul id="users-list"></ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Valeu pela ajuda

Comment: Bom dia estava estudando seu código e me surgiu uma dúvida é possivel colocar por após eu digitar F2 o que eu digitar no textarea ele filtrar na lista exemplo: Digitei F2 logo em seguida digitei rita aparecer somente rita na lista?

Comment: @EderLuca sim, é possivel, de varias maneiras... a textatea tem mais texto ou só vai ter o nome do usuario para a filtragem?

Comment: Infelizmente ele vai ter mais texto tipo esse textarea será um campo de comentários onde a pessoa colocará os usuários conforme a lista e continuará escrevendo